# lightning-record-form not work correct in Spring ‘20

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form, spring-20

I found that lightning-record-form does not work correct.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-form
         record-id="anyAccountId"
         object-api-name="Account"
         layout-type="Full"
         mode="view"
         columns="2">
    </lightning-record-form>
</template>
```

if you try to edit it it will not work,
component is hide. And only save and cancel buttons are shown. If click to cancel everything is hided.
This issue affected CS2 sf instance but works fine in NA59.

Comment: The first thing to look at is whether there were any [critical updates](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_cruc.htm?edition=&impact=) applied on your org that might affect the behaviour you are seeing. For example, perhaps you are using community or guest user access and there is a need to update the user profile.

Comment: Thanks for this. Now it works fine.

Comment: i'm having the same issue, can you tell me how you fixed it?

Comment: Hi @sfdxdev go to https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001GqH9QAK and check if you org is updated
patch 11 fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is caused by this issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001GqH9QAK
Hopefully will be fixed with patch 11.0

Comment: It is not reproduced now. Looks like it is fixed.

Comment: Yes, the patch was just released on CS2

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to [critical updates](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_cruc.htm?edition=&impact=) applied on the org that might affect the behaviour you are seeing.

For example, perhaps you are using community or guest user access and there is a need to update the user profile.

Specifically note newly enforced critical updates - these are the ones most likely to have tripped you up here.

Comment: thanks https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=224011000
this is fix for issue

Comment: I suggest you upvote drozdps's answer and mark as best answer.